# Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.healthmarketscience:rmiio:jar:2.0.4 in xyz

Tags: azure, maven, azure-pipelines, pipeline

Could you please help me how can I fix this issue? I couldn't do this also failed

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.healthmarketscience:rmiio:jar:2.0.4 in CardsOnTheSpot (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/PROJECT/_packaging/FEED/maven/v1)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:750)

mvn -e -X deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/PROJECT/_packaging/FEED/maven/v1 -DrepositoryId=cots6 -Dfile=C:\Users\ramku\.m2\repository\com\healthmarketscience\rmiio\2.0.4\rmiio-2.0.4.jar  -Dversion=2.0.4 -DgroupId=com.healthmarketscience.rmiio -DartifactId=rmiio -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true

Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: transfer failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/PROJECT/_packaging/FEED/maven/v1/com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/rmiio/2.0.4/rmiio-2.0.4.jar, status: 409 Conflict - 'com.healthmarketscience.rmiio:rmiio:2.0.4' cannot be published to the feed because it exists in at least one of the feed's upstream sources. Publishing this copy would prevent you from using 'com.healthmarketscience.rmiio:rmiio:2.0.4' from 'Maven Central'. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864880 (DevOps Activity ID: ED8CA47C-F06D-43B3-AAF2-26073C16ED93)

Comment: it looks like the artifact is already present in the target feed, Can you use the same artifact? Instead of publishing it again? Or delete the artifact from target feed and publish it again?

Comment: I deleted the artifact from the feed, and deleted the feed also, and trying with a different feed (new feed that I created), still getting a build error.   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pslib: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ps:pslib:jar:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.healthmarketscience:rmiio:jar:2.0.4 in ORGNAME

Comment: Could not find artifact com.healthmarketscience:rmiio:jar:2.0.4 in ORGNAME –> Can you add the Build step to built the artifact again? and then use the artifact from maven built in the feed artifact task?